# Control Excerpt Length Using Filters not working at all

Tags: wordpress, function

I'm trying to trim the `excerpt length` by using filters:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

But it is not working at all.

I put it in my `functions.php` in my theme but it does nothing. I don't get an error, nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any plugin that could trim the excerpt in the similar manner? Try adding a special prefix to your function `myname_custom_excerpt_length`. Or increase the priority (the number at the end)...

Comment: @dingo_d I deactivate all plugins and everything you mentioned and still does not work. For the moment, I'm using a plugin.

Comment: This is really odd, because this code should work...

Comment: I have same issuie. Did you slove